# Lat/Long equation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, latitude-longitude

I am trying to find an equation for finding the lat/long point between two lat/long points in Javascript.  It would work something like this.

`getMiddle(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2)` <= would return [lat3, lat3] halfway distance wise (going around the earth obviously).

I found this:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223101843/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51822.html)

> Date: 10/11/2001 at 11:41:08
> From: Doctor Rick
> Subject: Re: Determining lat and long of a point between two given
> points
>
> Hi, Chuck.
>
> This will probably be a little more complicated than you think. The
> easiest way for me to do it is to think in terms of vectors. Some of
> the items in our Archives on the topic of latitude and longitude use
> the vector approach, so you can see them for background. For example:
>
> Distance Between Two Points on the Earth
> [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223110612/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51722.html)
>
> Let's call the two points A and B, and choose a rectangular coordinate
> system in which the equator is in the x-y plane and the longitude of
> point A is in the x-z plane. Let lat1 be the latitude of A, let lat2
> be the latitude of B, and let dlat be the longitude of B minus the
> longitude of A. Finally, use distance units such that the radius of
> the earth is 1. Then the vectors from the center of the earth to A and
> B are
>
> A = (cos(lat1), 0, sin(lat1))   B = (cos(lat2)*cos(dlon),
> cos(lat2)*sin(dlon), sin(lat2))
>
> Point C, the midpoint of the shortest line between A and B, lies along
> the sum of vectors A and B. (This works because A and B have the same
> length, so the sum of the vectors is the diagonal of a rhombus, and
> this diagonal bisects the angle.)
>
> A+B = (cos(lat1)+cos(lat2)*cos(dlon),
> cos(lat2)*sin(dlon),
> sin(lat1)+sin(lat2))
>
> To get the actual vector C, we need to scale this vector to length R
> so it ends at the surface of the earth. Thus we have to divide it by
> |A+B|, that is, the length of vector A+B. That would get pretty messy.
> But we can find the latitude lat3 and longitude difference (lon3-lon1)
> by looking at ratios of the coordinates of A+B, and these ratios are
> the same whether we scale the vector or not. To see this, look back at
> the formula for vector B. Knowing that vector, we can recover lat2 and
> dlon:
>
> dlon = tan^-1(B_y/B_x)   lat2 = tan^-1(B_z/sqrt(B_x^2+B_y^2))
>
> Here, B_x, B_y, and B_z are the x, y, and z coordinates of vector B.
>
> We can do the same thing with vector A+B to find the latitude and
> longitude of point C:
>
> dlon3 = tan^-1(cos(lat2)*sin(dlon)/
> (cos(lat1)+cos(lat2)*cos(dlon)))   lat3 = tan^-1((sin(lat1)+sin(lat2))/
> sqrt((cos(lat1)+cos(lat2)*cos(dlon))^2+
> (cos(lat2)*sin(dlon))^2))
>
> That's the formula you seek. Since both formulas involve division, we
> must consider the special cases. The longitude calculation fails when
> C_x = 0, that is, when C is 90 degrees away from A in longitude, so
> dlon3 will be +90 or -90; the sign depends on the sign of dlon. The
> latitude calculation fails when C_x and C_y are both zero, thus we
> know that in this case, lat3 = 0. A complete algorithm will check for
> these cases, but they won't occur if you're interested only in the
> continental US.
>
> When I plug in the latitudes and longitudes for LA and NYC, I get:
>
> LA 34.122222 118.4111111 NYC 40.66972222 73.94388889 midpt 39.54707861
> 97.201534
>
> I hope this is helpful to you.
>
> - Doctor Rick, The Math Forum   [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054714/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/)

Which I believe has the answer but not as Javascript.

This is what I am working with:

[image: image of the 3D globe]

I have spent some time creating map point and determining distance between them, but to find a midway point between them has been difficult for me.  Converting equations I have found so far has been unsuccessful.

Once I can find the midpoint I want to use recursion + (how many points I need between two points based on distance) to build properly spaced dotted lines.

Any help on this piece would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As the link you've provided could break, please quote the relevant section(s).

Comment: Do you mean the middle point between the points on the associated Great Circle, as described in this Wikipedia article? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: 1. added content to the link.

Comment: 2. yes the midpoint on the "great circle"

Comment: 3. I have tried converting equations I have found so far online (like the one attached, but 2 other ones as well).  Math has never been my strength.  So getting some help seemed like the right direction at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer in python: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577713-midpoint-of-two-gps-points/

- Convert to js
- Profit

Additionally: For those wanting to go straight to profit (yes I know I patched Math.  Borrowed shamelessly from here: https://nickthecoder.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/radian-and-degree-conversion-in-javascript/)

```
getMidpoint: function(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
    Math.degrees = function(rad) {
        return rad * (180 / Math.PI);
    }
    Math.radians = function(deg) {
        return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
    }
    lat1 = Math.radians(lat1);
    lng1 = Math.radians(lng1);
    lat2 = Math.radians(lat2);
    lng = Math.radians(lng2);
    bx = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lng - lng1)
    by = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(lng - lng1)
    lat3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(lat1) + Math.sin(lat2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(lat1) + bx) * (Math.cos(lat1) + bx) + Math.pow(by, 2)));
    lon3 = lng1 + Math.atan2(by, Math.cos(lat1) + bx);
    return [Math.round(Math.degrees(lat3), 5), Math.round(Math.degrees(lon3), 5)]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the formula you're looking for:

This is the half-way point along a great circle path between the two points.

```
Formula:    Bx = cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ
By = cos φ2 ⋅ sin Δλ
φm = atan2( sin φ1 + sin φ2, √(cos φ1 + Bx)² + By² )
λm = λ1 + atan2(By, cos(φ1)+Bx)

JavaScript:
(all angles 
in radians)
var Bx = Math.cos(φ2) * Math.cos(λ2-λ1);
var By = Math.cos(φ2) * Math.sin(λ2-λ1);
var φ3 = Math.atan2(Math.sin(φ1) + Math.sin(φ2),
                    Math.sqrt( (Math.cos(φ1)+Bx)*(Math.cos(φ1)+Bx) + By*By ) );
var λ3 = λ1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(φ1) + Bx);
```

source: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Dan thanks for the help.  Was able to find a solution in Python a friend shared with me.  Trying to get him to post it here to mark as the answer.   I will also share the JS version.